# How do I debug a callback function used in a jQuery bind() call with Chrome DevTools?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to put a breakpoint in a function that is passed as a callback to the bind() call in jQuery. The javascript is initialized in a document.ready event.
I want to examine some variables when the callback is fired, but setting a breakpoint in the script won't halt the debugger when the event is fired.

What do I need to do to make it hit the breakpoint? Here's the script. I want to break on line 6.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#avtalsinformationForm").bind('invalid-form.validate',
            function (form, validator) {
                var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
                if (errors) {
                    validator.errorList[0].element.focus();
                }
            }
        );
    });
```

Comment: If adding the breakpoint from the devtools itself doesn't work (and it should) simply type the word `debugger;` before line 6 and it'll throw you into the debugger.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly putting a `debugger` statement into the function code?

Comment: Good point, both of you. It seems that the callback isn't fired on the first validation failure, but if I try to submit the form again (which this snippet applies to) then the callback is fired. Very weird.